# Special characters conversion from a JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, special-characters

I'm receiving the following string *(Artist name - Song name)* with unreadable characters from a [JSON file](https://radio.indybay.org/status-json.xsl):
**Las CrÃ¨me BrÃ»lÃ©e - QuiÃ©reme Siempre**

Is there any way to convert these and other unreadable characters into a proper string with special characters via a Javascript or jQuery function?

In the example provided, this is how the string should be read:
**Las Crème Brûlée - Quiéreme Siempre**

**Project background**
The string is read from a [JSON file](https://radio.indybay.org/status-json.xsl) generated from an Icecast mountpoint. For those unfamiliar, Icecast is a streaming server and, for some reason, the streaming software (SAM Broadcaster) is sending the song names without the characters properly encoded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escaping the string will generate a UTF-8 encoded string and then turn it back into a JavaScript UCS-2 string with `decodeURIComponent()`.

```js
console.log(decodeURIComponent(escape('Las CrÃ¨me BrÃ»lÃ©e - QuiÃ©reme Siempre')));
```